# Создание уведомлений на Андроид

Tags: java, android, уведомления

Всем доброго времени суток, пожалуйста, помогите. Проблема в том, что уведомления мои показываются раньше времени. К примеру, должны показаться минут через 15 (время передаю верно), но появляются они сразу же после выполнения метода (вызывается нажатием кнопки), когда таймер еще отрицательный.

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void showNotification(View view) throws ParseException, InterruptedException {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotificatonActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0 , intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        //Notification Channel
        CharSequence channelName = NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID;
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW;
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, importance);
        notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
        notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
        notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
        notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});


        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);

        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");
        Date date = new Date();

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 50);
        calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+3"));

        date = calendar.getTime();

        long when = date.getTime();

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.medicine)
                .setWhen(when)
                .setUsesChronometer(true)
                .setContentTitle("ContentTittle")
                .setContentText("ContentText");

        Notification notification = builder.build();

        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
        NOTIFICATION_ID++;
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]